# Thunar custom action: Extraction to subdirectories

Tags: command-line, tar, gzip, command-substitution, thunar

I am attempting to create a Custom Action in Thunar (File Manager) that will extract a `gzip` archive into a subdirectory of the same name (e.g. `abc.tar.gz` to `abc/`). I created this command, which works, although it puts single quotes around the file name (e.g. `'abc'/` instead of `abc/`). I ran the equivalent command manually and it doesn't contain single quotes. how can i remove them, and where are they coming from? Is there a better method of doing this?

```
tar -xzvf %n -C "$(f="%n"; g=${f%%.tar.gz}; mkdir -p $g; echo $g)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try removing the quotation marks around `%n`. It appears that thunar puts its own marks there, which is why you have them in the folder name.

Also, when you check thunar's examples, they never put the marks around expanded variables.

Comment: ok, that worked. i'm familiar with surrounding variable values with quotes, so i didn't consider that thunar might do it for me. this was a pretty silly mistake. thanks!